# Install perl-Mcrypt on Centos 6.5

Tags: perl, perl-module

i need to install perl-Mcrypt On CentOs6.5/32bit.

with cpan I get the following error:

```
[root@name ~]# cpan
cpan[1]>install Mcrypt

CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
  LWP not available
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp31072'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp31072'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
No external ftp command available

Client not fully configured, please proceed with configuring.

You have not configured a urllist and do not allow connections to the
internet to get a list of mirrors.  If you wish to get a list of CPAN
mirrors to pick from, use this command

    o conf init connect_to_internet_ok urllist

If you do not wish to get a list of mirrors and would prefer to set
your urllist manually, use just this command instead

    o conf init urllist

  LWP not available
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp31072'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp31072'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
No external ftp command available
```

How to fix it?

(also I dont Know How to Config Cpan)

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `perl-libwww-perl` package installed?

Answer (score 1):

Its might be a problem of proxy setting. set up `http_proxy` variable in `cpan`.

You can see here about configuration of web proxy (may be its not a right way but you can get some idea from here)
http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/08/configuring-web-proxy-on-centos.html